# tkz euclide plot coordinate system without ticks but on a specified interval

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot, tkz-base

How could I remove the number on the axis and nevertheless define the domain and range to plot? (because I have already an checkered background in my latex file.)

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{tikzpicture}
   %\tkzInit[xmax=6,ymax=6,xmin=-6,ymin=-6]
   %\tkzGrid
   \tkzAxeXY
   %\draw[ thick,latex-latex] (-1,4) -- (4,-6) node[anchor=south west] {$a$}; % two points for drawing 2x+y=2
  %\tkzText[above](0,6.75){Desired Output}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Japser code dont works for me. Instead, works the code:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tkzInit[xmax=6,ymax=6,xmin=-6,ymin=-6]
        %\tkzGrid
        %\tkzAxeXY
        \tkzSetUpAxis[line width=1pt,tickwd=0pt,ticka=0pt,tickb=0pt]
        \tkzDrawX
        \tkzDrawY
        %\draw[ thick,latex-latex] (-1,4) -- (4,-6) node[anchor=south west] {$a$}; % two points for drawing 2x+y=2
        %\tkzText[above](0,6.75){Desired Output}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

The output is:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

So, you want no ticks and no labels? Then you should use `\tkzDrawXY` instead of `\tkzAxeXY` which will not show labels. To remove the ticks, you need to set their width to zero using `\tkzSetUpAxis` (see the [`tkz-base` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tkz/tkz-base/doc/tkz-base.pdf) for more information):

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
   %\tkzInit[xmax=6,ymax=6,xmin=-6,ymin=-6]
   %\tkzGrid
   %\tkzAxeXY
   \tkzSetUpAxis[line width=1pt,tickwd=0pt,ticka=0pt,tickb=0pt]
   \tkzDrawXY
   %\draw[ thick,latex-latex] (-1,4) -- (4,-6) node[anchor=south west] {$a$}; % two points for drawing 2x+y=2
  %\tkzText[above](0,6.75){Desired Output}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Jasper Habicht. And how can I manange that all 4 quadrants are plotted instead of only the first one?

Comment: Uncomment `\tkzInit[xmax=6,ymax=6,xmin=-6,ymin=-6]`.